# Problema con cambio de nivel y secuencias

Tags: unreal-engine

mi problema es que estoy intentando hacer que cuando acabe una secuencia,se cambie a otro nivel,pero me resulta imposible hacerlo.
Gracias de antemano y hasta luego

Answer (score 0):

Yo le pondría al principio un bloque llamado sequence, en el primer nodo (then 0)ejecuta tu cinemática, y en Then 1 pon un delay con lo que dure la misma, y al acabar el delay pon open level con el nombre del nivel, esto solo funciona con blueprints